# new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass)) Causing Memory corruption?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got an application that loads an assembly dynamically:

```
 Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("MyClass.DLL");
 Type type = asm.GetType("MyClass");

 MyClass runningAssembly = (MyClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
 runningAssembly.start();
```

Once loaded and the start() method is called, this line of code is executed:

```
 XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
```

And the following exception is thrown:

```
 "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."
```

I've been stumbling on the cause of this and haven't been able to get a grasp on it. Does anyone have any tips? I also cannot seem to trap this error... it blows right through the try/catch.

By the way, the error doesn't *always* happen. Sometimes in debug mode it works fine, but it seems like once it starts, it'll always happen even after restarting Visual Studio. A reboot clears it up and allows it to work at least once. It also happens when running from the compiled EXE.

**EDIT**

I tried the same thing but without loading the assembly dynamically. I called it as a class directly, i.e:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.start();
```

And the same problem persists, so it does NOT appear to be related to being loaded dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to now what causes the problems without knowing anything about `MyClass`. Whats in the constructor and especially what is in the `start()` method? Does the code have any unsafe code? If you are addressing unsafe memory you could very likely experience the described behavior.

If your `start()` method is starting a new thread and an exception is thrown on the new thread you will not catch it in a try/catch around the `start` method.